Does setting 'Inactive Tabs' setting to 'Never Move' restore or delete inactive tabs (iOS)?
Per the title really. In Chrome on iPhone there is an option to turn off the 'Inactive Tabs' feature. Currently inactive tabs cannot be bookmarked so I'd like to revert inactive tabs back to active. So the question is does setting the Inactive Tab setting to 'Never Move' actually restore or delete currently inactive tabs?
